# installing errors Ruby on Rails (Windows 7 & 10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3-ruby

I already searched for a lot of questions on the internet but couldn't solve the error.
I tried on both Windows 7 and 10 but ran into the same error.
After I installed Ruby and Rails and sqlite3, and typed in `rails new myproject` in a command windows, I see an error saying sqlite3.h is missing.

https://medium.com/@declancronje/installing-and-troubleshooting-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-windows-10-fix-87c8886d03b

I found this link explaining how to fix sqlite3 issue on Windows. After I followed the instruction and typed in `bundle install` the result said `the system cannot find the path specified`
Could anyone help me out please? I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days..
I use ruby (2.3.3), rails (5.0.1), and sqlite3 (3.33.0). I thought it was due to sqlite3 version compatibility so I tried to find sqlite3 1.4.2. but there's no way to download this from the internet.

Comment: What kind of windows you installed rails ? Windows 32 bit or windows 64 bit ?
I suggest you follow this website to install rails, very ok with no problem.
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/how-to-install-rubyonrails-on-windows-7-8-10-complete-tutorial-2017-fc95720ee059)

Comment: A screenshot and more context would help here.

Answer (score 0):

I see.
I suggest you use Docker instead.
You can install Docker on your PC and create your Ruby on Rails Apps.

https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/

Once you there, you have to create a Dockerfile where you are installing ruby and rails, and generate your app.

You could also check the docker and rails documentation that you can find on internet.

Another way to install Rails on Windows is to install WSL2.
And there you can install it as well. (This is the best option.)